# Is there any undo command for clear in Linux?

Tags: ubuntu

I accidentally cleared my screen and I need to see my previous output, any way to see output/results of previous commands?
I understand that I can see my past commands using history command but I am not looking for that

Comment: You might be able to just scroll up in your terminal window

Comment: No, Like I said I have already cleared

Comment: Most terminal emulators implement clearing by simply scrolling down until the prompt is at the top.

Comment: Are you talking about a terminal emulator? If so, which one? Does Alt+PgUp let you scroll up to the past commands?  How did you clear your screen? Did you just run `clear`? Please [edit] your question and explain what you need in more detail.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can we undo the clear command in Linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/689377/how-can-we-undo-the-clear-command-in-linux)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `!!`. This command prints the output of the last command you ran.
For example:

```
me@dev:~$ cat test.txt
This is the test file.
```

And i cleared my screen.. Then i ran the `!!` command. And output is here:

```
me@dev:~$ !!
cat test.txt
This is the test file.
```

Look [here](https://www.makeuseof.com/linux-bash-terminal-shortcuts/) for more..

**NOTE: You shouldn't use `clear` while clean your screen, instead you should use Ctrl+L because terminal remembers `clear` as the last command.**