# How can we undo the clear command in Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line

`clear` clears the screen of the terminal.

Is there any command that can restore the original screen contents from before `clear` was run, effectively undoing that `clear`?

Comment: `ctrl-z` to suspend a task OR undo OR something else?

Comment: What would you expect to be the opposite of clearing the screen?

Comment: @roaima I expect to see previous results in my terminal. the clear command removes results and clears the screen. I want to take it back and see that result.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor undo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean undo, then there is ★nothing. Except, you can go through the command history and re-run a command. If the command is idempotent, then you will get the same result.

Footnotes:
★ nothing unless you use some sort of logging system. This logging may be part of a terminal program, or separate. It is not part of the kernel called Linux.

Comment: It might have to be not only the command that was idempotent but the context too. Consider `ls -l file` for a file that existed, followed by `rm -f file` a little later

Answer (score 3):

There is no direct opposite of the `clear` command, which clears a terminal screen.

However, some implementations of a command line terminal emulator offer a scroll-back buffer. This buffer may keep previous lines of output. For example, using these commands in `mintty` from Cygwin to generate text and then clear the screen I find that I am able to scroll back to the previous result. However, this is implemented purely as part of a terminal emulator and is unlikely to be accessible programmatically:

```
yes | head -n20 | nl     # Generate 20 lines of unique output
yes n | head -n20 | nl   # And some more
```

[image: 20 lines of output]

```
clear
```

[image: screen cleared]

After scroll-back

[image: scroll-back buffer]

Answer (score 3):

If using the `tmux` terminal emulator/multiplexer, you could define an undoable `clear` as:

```
clear() {
  tmux capture-pane -eb c &&
    tput sc &&
    command clear "$@"
}
```

And `unclear` as:

```
unclear() {
  tput home && tmux show-buffer -b c && tput rc
}
```

Where `clear` captures the contents of the screen into the `c` buffer and `s`aves the `c`ursor position before clearing and `unclear` dumps the contents of that buffer after having moved  the cursor to the home position (top-left) and then `r`estores the `c`ursor position.